# Null and isEmpty Check for ArrayLists

Tags: java

How to do null check and also isEmpty check on a arraylist. Any best practices around it.

I have if  then else if then else if loops

if listA not null and not empty also listB not null and not empty i have to call database twice (first time listA data, second time using listB data). Then merge both results using addAll

In first else if listA has data whereas listB is null or empty call only listA specific database call using that stored procedure

in second else if listB has data whereas listA is null or empty call only listA specific database call using that stored procedure

For me with null flows are working while passing blank list [] not working.

How to check both null and isEmpty same time?
if list null and if i check isEmpty giving null pointer exception.

Comment: Can you show your code and where exactly you have a problem?

Comment: What do you mean if the list is null ? If it hasn't been initialized yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Check `null` before `isEmpty`

You'll just have to check for `null` before `isEmpty` each time. You could quickly create a method to help you, ie:

```
private boolean isNullOrEmpty(List list) {
   return list == null || list.isEmpty();
}
```

This won't cause a null pointer exception since it will not check for the 2nd condition if the first is true. ([Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation))

Comment: Good Answer. I prefer using [`Objects.isNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#isNull(java.lang.Object)), but same effect: `return Objects.isNull( list ) || list.isEmpty() ;`

Comment: Actually, you could make that method even more generally useful by taking arguments of [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) rather than `List`, like this: `boolean isNullOrEmpty( Collection collection ) { return Objects.isNull( collection ) || collection.isEmpty() ; }` for use with lists, sets, and so on. All `Collection` classes must have an `isEmpty` method.

Comment: I see other part of the code developers used CollectionUtils.isEmpty() . Is that is good choice?

Comment: I have a validator class where i am trying to set value as null if blank comes but getting compilation error. How to set setter to null?     I have
invoiceRequest.setInfoList() which i am trying to assign to null as below but compiler is not happy about it it
invoiceRequest.setInvoiceInfoList()=null;

At beginning of this method I have declared it as below    public void validateReq(InvoiceRequest request, List<String> displayErrors){
InvoiceRequest invoiceRequest=(InvoiceRequest)request;
......
......
......
invoiceRequest.setInvoiceInfoList()=null;

Comment: below is the variable name in the InvoiceRequest Pojo class for which Editor/IDE/Framework creating getters, setters,    private List<InvoiceInfo> invoiceInfoList;

Comment: invoiceRequest.setInvoiceInfoList()=null;
 I just have to do as below to set null
invoiceRequest.setInvoiceInfoList(null);